# rails and dynamic javascript?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, paperclip

Hey guys, I am trying to tie the recently popular [jQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) with Rails 3 (with a Paperclip back-end though that's not yet pertinent to this question).

This jQuery plugin basically allows for multiple file uploads. I was reading [this page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data) for information on how to pass along additional POST data with each upload. This is where I'm having trouble. Here's the code that the page gives as an example:

```
  $('.upload').fileUploadUI({
      uploadTable: $('.upload_files'),
      downloadTable: $('.download_files'),
      buildUploadRow: function (files, index) {
          var file = files[index];
          return $(
              '<tr>' +
              '<td class="file_upload_start">' +
              '<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" title="Start Upload">' +
              '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-n">Start Upload<\/span>' +
              '<\/div>' +
              '<\/td>' +
              '<td>' + file.name + '<\/td>' +
              '<td class="file_upload_desc"><input type="text" title="File description"><\/td>' +
              '<td class="file_upload_progress"><div><\/div><\/td>' +
              '<td class="file_upload_cancel">' +
              '<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" title="Cancel">' +
              '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel">Cancel<\/span>' +
              '<\/div>' +
              '<\/td>' +
              '<\/tr>'
          );
      },
      // ...
```

The part I need to replace is the input text-box in `file_upload_desc`. Instead of that, I need to include a dropdown control constructed with:

```
f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name
```

This works in a static view, but I need to add this each time a file is selected for upload.

My confusion lies in where and how to manage the passing of the dynamic dropdown (dynamic since it depends on knowing which categories exist) to the static view.

Would it have something to do with creating some view partial, then do something like:

```
$.get("/partial", function(data) {
  // blah blah
});
```

The problem is that per the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options),the `buildUploadRow` must return the html, so I would have to get the returned data and concatenate it to the return result, or something.

***One possibility*** is to write this out in the static view once, then whenever I need to dynamically add it when an upload is marked, `clone()` it, while remembering to get rid of the original to avoid it interfering with the POSTed data.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways to go about this:

1. Add the collection_select to another part of your page, that is not within your uploader form, and hiding it from the user (display: none). Keep this one collection_select as your reference and simply clone it when you want to add a new file uploader row. Make sure you add the collection_select as a hidden element in another area of your page so that it doesn't get submitted as well.
2. Create a single collection_select as your first file uploader row using Rails, and then simply clone the first one when you need another.
3. Use Rails to insert the collection_select directly into the javascript function, as a string, on your page. Make sure to escape_javascript the string so that it's valid Javascript. Using this approach your collection_select will already be embedded into the buildUploadRow function.

Comment: Thank you Pan I really appreciate the response. I would actually like to do it using option number 3, but that's where I'm confused. In what file would I do the call? Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime I'm going to try option 2.

Comment: To implement option #3 you'll have to use inline javascript on the file uploader page and insert your collection select using the <%= ... %> erb tags. For example javascript_string = "<%= escape_javascript(collection_select @object, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name)%>";

Comment: Right, my confusion was what file to place this in, but I think I can just put it in the same view using a script tag and content_for :scripts

Comment: That sounds right to me. You basically want the same page that reneders the file uploader form to be the one that defines the javascript. Whether that is using a content_for or another javascript tag is up to you, but it should be on the same page.

Comment: Thanks, your help has guided me a good distance. I'll try and figure it out from here and if I can't, I'll post another question. Thanks again!